# Calculating t-value for regression coefficients

Tags: t-test, excel, nonlinear

I am estimating a nonlinear model as follows:

$$Y=B_0+B_1X_1+B_2X_2+B_3aX_3^{1-b}+B_4$$

I have estimated $B_0$, $B_1$, $B_2$, $B_3$, $B_4$, $a$, and $b$ using least squares in Excel (minimizing SSR using solver). I was wondering how to get the t-values for all of the estimates/coefficients.

Comment: Wat does the star mean? Does it mean multiplication?

Comment: Yes sorry about that...

Comment: You cannot estimate $a$ and $B_3$ separately. You can only estimate $B_3 a$.

Comment: @Viktor the model above was a simplified example. I didn't realize after estimation computing t values would be such a hassle. I think I will try to use nlme in R to get the estimates instead- they should definitely come with t-values.

Answer (score 0):

Nonlinear regression is not an easy object to deal with. One of the classes of the approaches is one-step estimators (e.g., see [recent papers by Yu.Yu.Linke](https://www.scopus.com/authid/detail.uri?authorId=15520066600)).